# How to use algebraic data type for scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am using scalatest as following:

```
class AuthLdapSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "The user" should "be signin successfully." in {

    AuthLdap.signin("user@example.com")("password").value.unsafeRunSync() match {
      case Right(r) => println(r)
      case Left(l) => println(l)
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, the function `AuthLdap.signin("user@example.com")("password").value.unsafeRunSync()` returns `Either[A, B]`.
How can I validate if the return type is `Right` or `Left`?
I've tried as following:

```
AuthLdap.signin("user@example.com")("password").value.unsafeRunSync() should be (Right)
```

But the compiler complains:

> Error:(15, 93) [Artima SuperSafe] Values of type
>   Either[String,io.khinkali.auth.AuthLdapUser] and scala.util.Right.type
>   may not be compared for equality with ScalaTest's be matcher syntax.
>   If you really want this expression to compile, configure Artima
>   SuperSafe to allow Either[String,io.khinkali.auth.AuthLdapUser] and
>   scala.util.Right.type to be compared for equality.  For more
>   information on this kind of error, see:
>   http://www.artima.com/supersafe_user_guide.html#safer-equality

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you just want to assert that it is a 'Right' with any value

```
AuthLdap.signin("user@example.com")("password").value.unsafeRunSync().isRight should be true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the relevant [ScalaTest documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/other_goodies#eitherValues)

Essentially, you check it via

```
AuthLdap.signin("user@example.com")("password").value.unsafeRunSync().right should be "user@example.com"`
```

or whatever your `Right` value should be